# How to fit an image loaded from sqlite blob field in Delphi 10.1 Berlin TImageViewer?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to show a previously saved image in a blob field with Delphi's `TImageViewer`  component. I am developing with Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

The image does not fit in the `TImageViewer` component, even using the `BestFit` command, as shown below. The image is bigger than the component. But it fits in the component if the image does not come from a database field.

Here is my code:

```
BlobStream := qryFoto.CreateBlobStream(qryFoto.FieldByName('image'), TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
Image1.BestFit;
BlobStream.Free;
```

How to fit it?

Comment: Have you tried setting Strecht property to True ?.

Comment: I didn't find strecht property in TImageViewer component. It has? When i was using TImage, and set strecht property, the image became distorted.

Comment: @RicardoPin Your code worked fine for me in a new project using the TImageViewer. You can also try use a **TMemoryStream** instead of a **TStream** and use this code: `TBlobField(qryFoto.FieldByName('image')).SaveToStream(BlobStream);` to create the stream.

Comment: My fault, I thought you were using a TImage. By the way, you can set Proportional to True to avoid a TImage getting distorted.